# Espaçamento entre botões

Tags: html5, css3

Quero diminuir o espaçamento desses botões porém não estou conseguindo. Já tentei colocar margin e padding e nada. Não quero utilizar uma lista. Como posso fazer?

Segue o código html:

```
<div id="buttonbar">
     <button id="volDn"><img src="images/video/menos.png" id="menos"/></button>
     <button id="volUp"><img src="images/video/mais.png" id="btn-mais"/></button>
     <button id="mute"><img src="images/video/som.png" id="btn-mudo"/></button>
 </div>
```

O css:

```
#buttonbar{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Você tentou usar um margin negativo?

Comment: "hmmm" não vou tentar pera ai

Comment: amigo se eu uso padding ou margin sendo negativo ou positivo ele reposiciona a imagem e não mexe no espeçamento

Comment: qual espaçamento você quer dizer? a distancia entre um e outro?

Comment: exatamente eles estão muito distantes um do outro queria junta-los mais so lembrando que eles estão inline ou seja um do lado do outro

Comment: #volDn{
  margin-right:-2px;
} , o botão do meio vai ficar mais perto do da esquerda, ai tu arruma como quiser

Comment: não deu certo não mexeu no espaçamento

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Faça o seguinte, adicione esse código no CSS

```
#buttonbar button{

  margin:-2px;

}
```

Quanto menor o número mais próximos estarão um do outro

Comment: "vlwwwwww" deu certo obrigadão daqui a 6 min  eu marco como resposta aceita

Comment: @Kirito Fico feliz por ter funcionado :D

Answer (score 5):

Você não consegue remover o espaço pois o navegador coloca um caracter de espaço entre os botões (devido a um espaço, quebra de linha ou identação no próprio código). Seguem duas soluções possíveis e fáceis de implementar.

**1.** Não deixar quebra de linha entre os botões. O código pode ficar poluído, mas é a solução mais simples para casos bem específicos.

```
<button ...>...</button><button ...>...</button><button ...>...</button>
```

---

**2.** Utilizar `float` nos botões. Você pode adicionar um `float: left` nos botões e utilizar a técnica do [`clearfix`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/) no container para não gerar problemas na página.

```
/* Utilize classes no lugar de ids para casos mais genéricos */
.buttonbar:after {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    content: " ";
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
}

.buttonbar > button {
    float: left;
}
```